# Intermittent connectivity issues with Bluetooth keyboard

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, bluetooth

I am using a [Satechi Bluetooth Keyboard](https://a.co/d/hSmXOlI) to connect to a PC (Windows 10 22H2), MacBook Pro, and iPad. There are **no** connectivity issues with the Mac or iPad. The keyboard allows me to connect with multiple devices with a key combination (<kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>-<kbd>4</kbd>).

With the PC on any device setting of the keyboard (1-4), it will work for a short while after adding it as a Bluetooth device. If it has already been set up, the keyboard will either fail to respond or take about 30 seconds to "wake up". After waking up, if I hit a key then it will repeat that key for anywhere up to 50 times. If I try to remove the keyboard from **Settings** > **Devices** > **Bluetooth & other devices**, it will say "Remove failed".

- Connected the keyboard to my MacBook Pro using all four device settings on the keyboard and it works without any problems
- Connected an Apple Bluetooth keyboard to the PC without any problems.
- Connected an Xbox Bluetooth controller that works without any problems.
- Installed the latest Microsoft Bluetooth driver with the same results.

What is causing this intermittent issue and how can I fix it?

Addition info:

- [Gigabyte B450M DS3H WiFi Motherboard](https://a.co/d/f1k0Oa0)
- Realtek Bluetooth driver vers. 1.5.1012.3 (1/9/2018)